# Highlighted content (search column)

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, search, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

Can we do a custom query on the Description column (Multiple lines of text) in Highlighted content?

Can we say:

```
(Path:"https://test.sharepoint.com/test)AND(filetype:docx)AND(Description:"This is test")
```

Comment: Is this SharePoint default "Description" column or you have created a custom column?

Comment: Hi @Harris, is below solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test from my end and I was able to use the SharePoint default "Description" column in KQL query to filter the search results.

I have used below KQL query in the highlighted content web part:

```
Path:"https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Shared Documents" AND filetype:docx AND Description:"This is test"
```

And I got the correct results from specific SharePoint document library mentioned in `Path` property like this:

[image]

---

Here are the documents/files in my SharePoint document library:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your message. I have two Description columns; one came with Document set content type, and the other is a custom column. I am referring to the custom one with the AGRkMSDescription internal name. I have tried both display name and internal name and it didn't work.

Comment: For custom columns, you have to create the managed property > map it with crawled property and then use that new managed property name in your custom query. check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292959/how-to-sort-by-name-with-the-highlighted-content-web-part/292960#292960

Comment: Hi Harris, any update on this thread? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my below response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.